# Change a set to a dictionary - Django Python

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications

I am trying to combine these two views. This is what I have. MenuView is to combine with add_to_menu so that if the if statement returns negative, the menuview portion still runs and displays the menu on my html page. If the if the statement is positive, it still shows the menu, but also adds the entered information into the database. I can only get one or the other to work at a time.

When I run this, I get an error telling me it has to be a dictionary and not a set.
Views.py:

```
class MenuView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'mis446/edit-menu.html'
    context_object_name = 'show_menu'


def add_to_menu(request):

   if request.method == 'POST':
       if request.POST.get('name') and request.POST.get('price') and request.POST.get('nickname'):
        post=Product()
        post.name= request.POST.get('name')
        post.price= request.POST.get('price')
        post.slug= request.POST.get('nickname')
        post.save()
        model = Product
        context_object_name = {'show_menu'}
        return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu.html', context_object_name)  

   else:
        model = Product
        context_object_name = {'show_menu'}
        return render(request,'mis446/edit-menu.html')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afzvr.png)

Comment: Could you share the traceback please?

Comment: I added an image of the traceback. The show menu is so I can take every item from Product and print it in a for loop into the edit-menu page, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 reputation yet so i guess i can add answers but not comments lol? Anyways, from what you have maybe the: context_object_name = {"show_menu"} is the cause of the error considering it is a set and not a dictionary. To make it a dictionary you have to add a value to the key "show_menu". I may be wrong but might want to try it just incase. Again sorry for posting as answer and not comment...